# resolve java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space in NetBeans

Tags: netbeans

Currently I am using NetBeans-8.1 in 32-bit Windows 10. I'm getting the following error:

> java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space.

I already changed the memory size to `-Xmx1024m` in `netbeans.conf` file, added environment variables `-Xms1024m -Xmx1024m -XX:PermSize=64M -XX:MaxPermSize=256m` but still getting same error. Are there any problems with NetBeans on 32-bit operating systems? My system has 4GB of RAM.

Comment: May also be a problem with your code; mind sharing some of your code ?

Comment: When do you get this? 
-Right after you start netbeans?
-After a install (Compile)?
-Some time after you are working?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have correctly set the flags for NetBeans, otherwise it will not be recognized: NetBeans requires the -J prefix for arguments to the JVM.
So you need to use

`-J-Xms1024m -J-Xmx1024m`

Also you should be aware that Oracle states that Windows 32 bit is capable only of about 1.4GB - 1.6GB of heap. See http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/hotspotfaq-138619.html#gc_heap_32bit

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried with that.
I used -J-Xms1024m -J-Xmx1024m this same arguments. and also added netbeans_default_options="-J-client -J-Xss2m -J-Xms512m -J-Xmx1024m -J-XX:PermSize=512m  -J-Dapple.laf.useScreenMenuBar=true -J-Dapple.awt.graphics.UseQuartz=true -J-Dsun.java2d.noddraw=true -J-Dsun.zip.disableMemoryMapping=true -J-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -J-XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -J-XX:+CMSPermGenSweepingEnabled" in netbeans.conf


But still same problem. I thought its bcz of OS 32 bit and 4GB RAM. if any other solutions please suggest me

Comment: You can try to increase it even further until the JVM will tell you that it can not reserve memory for the heap. (It will fail on startup then)
```-J-Xms1400m -J-Xmx1400m```

Comment: If that does not solve your problem it will be hard to fix on 32bit OS. Is NetBeans itself using so much memory or is it the application you are launching? In the later case you must add the JVM arguments to the project / "run" configuration, not to NetBeans of course. (These will then not have a -J prefix.)

Comment: for more than 2GB (-J-Xmx2048m) netbeans not starting... Its not opening only

Comment: Yes that it because of the 32bit memory limit. Therefore try 1400m ... and see me previous comment regarding the question if NetBeans or your application runs OOM

Comment: I tried with -J-Xmx1800m, -J-Xmx1500m... Netbeans not opened for this. When i changed to -J-Xmx1024m its opened

Comment: You can try to remove the memory allocated to the PermSize to sqeeze out a little more usable heap, so PermSize=256m, Xmx1400m

Comment: netbeans_default_options="-J-client -J-Xss2m -J-Xms512m -J-Xmx1024m -J-XX:PermSize=512m  -J-Dapple.laf.useScreenMenuBar=true -J-Dapple.awt.graphics.UseQuartz=true -J-Dsun.java2d.noddraw=true -J-Dsun.zip.disableMemoryMapping=true -J-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -J-XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -J-XX:+CMSPermGenSweepingEnabled"

Comment: sir check this one

Comment: When does the OOM occur? Inside NetBeans or as part of your application?

Answer (score -1):

You should increase the `-Xmx` value, which is the maximum amount of memory the JVM can allocate for the heap. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14763095/3919155) for details about the flags.

For example, you could use `-Xmx4G` to allow it to use up to 4GB of memory on your system.